# Determining if a set of vectors spans $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, determinant

Consider the following set of vectors:

$\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1+i\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1+i\end{pmatrix}$. I wish to determine if they span $\mathbb{C}^3$ and if they are linearly dependent.

$\begin{vmatrix}1+i&0&1\\1&1+i&0\\0&1&1+i\end{vmatrix}=1+(1+i)^3\ne 0$ and so the vectors are linearly independent. In terms of span, I don't really know where to begin. We have the following system of equations:

$(i) \alpha +\alpha i+\gamma=x$

$(ii) \alpha +\beta +\beta i=y$

$(iii) \beta + \gamma +\gamma i=z$

I got these by rearranging the linear combination of these vectors by multiplying $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ by the vectors in that order.

We basically need to write $x,y,z$ in terms of $\alpha ,\beta,\gamma$ but I'm not sure how to do this succinctly. Any help would be great.

Comment: Since $\mathbb C^3$ has 3 dimensions, any 3 linearly independent vectors span it.

Comment: Did you mean $\ne0$ *and so the vectors are linearly* in*dependent*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Indeed - sorry for the typo

Comment: @coffeemath Is there a more elementary way of proving the result? We haven't yet covered this in class so I don't want to use methods that we haven't already proved

Comment: I don't follow how you got your equations labelled i,ii,iii. Please go through the seps by which you got those equations. In the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Probably the easiest / most elementary way is to write each of the standard basis vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ as a linear combination of the vectors you have. Equivalently, you can also just solve the system of equations you've written down as you would any system of linear equations in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, treating $x,y,z$ as known

Comment: To expand on the above comment, you are trying to solve the system: $$\left(\begin{matrix}1 + i & 0 & 1\\1 & 1 + i & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 + i\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha \\\beta \\\gamma\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}x \\y \\z\end{matrix}\right)$$ for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. You know the determinant of this matrix is nonzero, so you can just multiply the above with its inverse. For reference, your matrix is the change of basis matrix from your basis $\{(1 + i, 1 , 0)^T, (0, 1 + i, 1)^T, (1, 0, 1 + i)^T\}$ to the standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

Comment: Did you mean we need to write $\alpha ,\beta,\gamma$ in terms of $x,y,z$?